# MATLAB: Printing comparative columns for elements from different vectors

Tags: matlab, printf

I´m trying to printing comparative columns to compare elements with the same index of two or three differents vector.
I will illustrate my question with the next example

```
>> a = [5.47758 7.46578 3.45323]
a =

5.4776    7.4658    3.4532

>> b = [5.65432 4.45678 2.34789]

b =

5.6543    4.4568    2.3479
```

Now if I write

```
>> sprintf('%.2f %.2f\n',a, b)
```

I get the following response from Matlab

```
ans =
5.48 7.47
3.45 5.65
4.46 2.35`
```

But what the way I would like to see this presentation of values is this

```
ans =
5.48 5.65  
7.47 4.46 
3.45 2.35
```

How can I use the function sprintf (or other function or way) to get the above representation?
Thank you.

Comment: see this related question about how SPRINTF/FPRINTF/NUM2STR deal with such input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366680/how-can-i-create-a-cell-of-strings-out-of-a-meshgrid-in-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this problem by [concatenating](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html#f1-85019) `a` and `b` into one 2-by-3 matrix input argument:

```
>> sprintf('%.2f %.2f\n',[a; b])

ans =

5.48 5.65
7.47 4.46
3.45 2.35
```

The [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) function works by reusing the formatting string over and over as it traverses (in column order) the elements of each of the input arguments *in the order they are entered*. That's why in your example all the values of `a` get printed, *then* all the values of `b`, instead of interleaving the values of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just "printing" it on the screen, you could type on the MATLAB Console (or "Command Window"):

---

```
a = [5.47758 7.46578 3.45323];
b = [5.65432 4.45678 2.34789];

c = [a',b']; % Transposing each row vector into a column vector before forming a matrix

c =

    5.4776    5.6543
    7.4658    4.4568
    3.4532    2.3479
```

This will make it easier when you sort the matrix by rows, for example, using the command 'sortrows' (See the doc on 'sortrows' for its usage: "help sortrows" or "doc sortrows").

Comment: Welcome to SO, Y.T.. I've noticed you keep posting using new accounts. It's probably better to use just 1 account that has all your answers in one place. A moderator can help you with that if you like. Also, adding "Y.T." or a link to your blog to the end of your post isn't necessary or generally acceptable on SO. Your name is already on your post in the bottom right corner, and a link to your blog is already in your profile. I also suggest for all new users to give the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) a good read. ;)