# meshgrid equivalent for strings

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, string-concatenation, cell-array

I have two cells:

```
Months1 = {'F','G','H','J','K','M','N','Q','U','V','X','Z'};
Months2 = 2009:2014;
```

How do I generate all combinations without running a loop so that I achieve the following:

```
Combined = {'F09','F10','F11','',...,'G09',.....};
```

Basically all combinations of `Months1` and `Months2` as in `meshgrid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert cell array to indices with `grp2idx`, then use `meshgrid`, then `strcat` to combine strings. Before you also need to convert numeric `Months2` vector to cell array of strings.

```
[id1,id2] = meshgrid(grp2idx(Months1),Months2);
Months2cell = cellstr(num2str(id2(:)-2000,'%02d'))';
Combined = strcat( Months1(id1(:)), Months2cell );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need cells and can use char arrays only, this can work:

```
Months1 = ['F','G','H','J','K','M','N','Q','U','V','X','Z']';
Months2 = num2str((2009:2014)');

[x, y] = meshgrid(1:12, 1:6);
Combined = strcat(Months1(x(:)), Months2(y(:),:));
```

and you can then `reshape` if required. I'm not yet sure how to do this with cells, though.
Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366680/how-can-i-create-a-cell-of-strings-out-of-a-meshgrid-in-matlab) post.

Comment: It seems I was late by 34 seconds :)

Comment: You are right, no need to convert to cell. Although OP wanted F09, not F2009, so some processing required.

Answer (score 3):

My take on the problem would apply [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html), [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) (to handle any millennium) and [`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) to do the work:

```
yearStrings = datestr(datenum(num2str(Months2(:)),'yyyy'),'yy');
[ii,jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(Months2),1:numel(Months1));
Combined = strcat(Months1(jj(:)).',yearStrings(ii(:),:)).'
```

Note: Years change faster than the prefixed letters, so `Months2` goes first in `ndgrid`, then `Months1`. IMO, [this is more intuitive behavior than `meshgrid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22461766/2778484), which forces you to think in x,y space to predict how the outputs vary.

---

Or instead of the `strcat` line:

```
tmp = [Months1(jj(:)).',yearStrings(ii(:),:)].';
Combined = cellstr(reshape([tmp{:}],[],numel(ii)).').'
```